# Eclipse: support for fb-namespace (Facebook) in JSP-files

Tags: eclipse, facebook, jsp

I got a Java-project related to Facebook with a bunch of JSP-files and I'm supposed to check something and use parts of that in another project. If I open a JSP-file in Eclipse I see plenty of tags in the fb-namespace. All those are underlined as a warning and Eclipse says, e.g. `Unknown tag (fb:prompt-permission)`.

My problem is that I'm totally new to that Facebook-stuff and obviously I'd need the context-sensitive support from Eclipse as far as those fb-tags are concerned. From what I can tell there doesn't seem to be a tag-library.

Can anyone please tell me what I need to do to get the context-sensitive support here?

EDIT:
in some way related: [HTML: What is `xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651602/html-what-is-xmlnsfb-http-www-facebook-com-2008-fbml)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignore the warnings. The `fb:` "namespace" is a java a namespace - it is not a java taglib or anyting that eclipse can resolve. They are evaluated when the page is loaded, so there is not much you can do about it.

See [this page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/fbml) for what to include in the `xmlns` - that's the xhtml namespace part (unrelated to jsp)

Comment: Maybe "not much" could help? ;)

Comment: that's what the link I gave is for ;)

Comment: Well, reading that link I'm thinking that it explains how to import custom tags. However, I wanted to get a list of available default tags. And that's what you are saying isn't possible.